# Jmeter - using multiple HTTP Recordings called by a templated script

Tags: transactions, jmeter, monitoring, synthetic

Is it possible to have a JMeter script that would load and cycle through HTTP recorded tests?  I want to control what is monitored via a SQL DB that would release what sites and variables that are to be used by the script.  That would include an appropriate HTTP Recorded Test.  I don't want to have multiple scripts or one hugely long script to monitor these sites.  I know I can do it with just the HTTP status checks, but I need to do some in-depth synthetic transactions to control these sites adequately.  It would be a lot easier to automate things like maintenance modes, decommissions, and recording script modifications if I can do it this way.

Comment: don't get from your description - you already got your http requests recorded? stored in the database? and you want to pull it out & configure to run dynamically from JMeter?

Comment: The goal is a generic script that will get it's variables from a csv file created by a SQL server.  The file will contain all the information for the monitoring script.  Since I can't guarantee that the sites to use the same template for login and transactions, each one would have to be recorded.  I want to specify a local path to each recording.   So in essence, I want to do individual recordings, save them to individual files, and have the monitoring script load and execute them (much like a variable from a csv file would be loaded).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL statements like INSERT or UPDATE using JMeter. You will need to:

1. Add the relevant [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick the driver up
2. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) element to your Test Plan and specify database URL and credentials there
3. Use one of the following Test Elements:

   - [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
   - [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor)
   - [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor)

Assuming all above you should be able to run the necessary SQL queries and store what you need.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) for detailed instructions and example.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to monitor the actual web page transaction response times.  Going directly to the DB server would defeat the purpose of this monitor and not allowed in many cases as they are customer servers off site.